# How do I register a custom domain in Azure when I cannot add the Azure Web App hostname as a CNAME to our domain?

Tags: cdn, azure

Let's assume we're running a website on `greatwebsite.com`. This is a multilingual website, and we're using `/en`, `/de`, `/fr` as path prefixes to handle languages (and not via top level domains).

We're using a CDN to front the entire website, and `greatwebsite.com` is CNAME'd to `greatcdnprovider.com` which then gets dynamic content from the configured origin.

We're in the process of launching a new version of this website, and we want to do this per language. We'll start with a small segment (language). The new website runs on Azure.

Our CDN is capable of using different origins based on request path. What we want to do then is to start off with sending all requests for `greatwebsite.com/[insert-language-here]` to the new Azure Web App, while all other languages goes to the current website.

Now, we're unable to add any CNAME or A record to `greatwebsite.com`, because we've already CNAME'd it to `greatcdnprovider.com`.

So what do we do then during this transition?

One idea is to create a subdomain `azure.greatwebsite.com` and CNAME that one to the Azure Web App. Then, we'll have the CDN to use `azure.greatwebsite.com` as it's origin for requests to`greatwebsite.com/en`.

So, `greatwebsite.com` gets CNAME'd to `greatcdnprovided.com` which then use `azure.greatwebsite.com` which again is CNAME'd or has an A record to our Azure web app.

Does that sound like the way to go, or do we have other options?